# Filling several JTextFields from DB

Tags: java, jdbc, jtextfield

I want to fill several JTextFields with data retrieved from a database.
I know, I could do something like:

```
while (rs.next()) {
   tfName.setText(rs.getString("name"));
   tfAge.setText(rs.getString("age"));
}
```

But is there a smarter approach with only one `return` at the end of the select method?

Comment: To which select method are you referring ? Also note that having such a `while` loop which updates your `JTextField` instances doesn't make much sense, since each `JTextField` can only contain one `String` as text. You might as well take the last entry of the `ResultSet` directly

Comment: This was just an example, in my case I would receive one result only. I mean a general select method in the database class.

Answer (score 1):

You could put your JTextFields in a `Map<String, JTextField>` and then use the database column key strings as keys for the text field map (say called fieldMap) and also have an array of these key strings. then you could do something like:

```
while (rs.next()) {
  for (String key: KEY_STRINGS) {
    fieldMap.get(key).setText(rs.getString(key));
  }
}
```

Having said this, the `while (rs.next())` bugs me a bit as I fear that the while will quickly loop through the database rows and will only truly display the last row of the database. This would need to be changed.